# Long term expected win rate

Tags: probability, markov-process

I have the following game, you have some initial probability $p_i$ to win, every time you try and lose the probability increases by a constant $p_a$ and is reset to $p_i$ when you win.

For example if you lost 4 times the probability to win on the 5th would be $p_i+3*p_a$. I'm interested in finding the long term expected win rate, which I know how to find; (construct a Markov's chain with the possible states and find the stationary distribution).

However the 'game' is modified such that, in addition to you 'rolling' for a win every $k$ amount of rolls you gain $p_a$ which is additive to your current win probability. And here is where I'm not sure how to find the expected win rate, can I calculate the stationary distribution for the simplified case and add $\frac{1}{k}*p_a$ to it?

edit: I'll try to be a little clearer about the second part, perhaps a better way to describe it is with time, you continue to gamble as in the first part with a certain period say every 10 seconds. Independently with a different period say 15 seconds your probability to win is increased by the same bonus $p_a$ which is also reset if you win, that bonus is granted irrespective of you winning or losing. For example, you gamble every 2 seconds with the initial rules, in addition every 5 seconds your chance to win is incremented by $p_a$.

So in this example, at time 0 round 1 happens, I lose ($p=p_i$), at time 2 I lose again ($p=p_i+p_a$), time 4 3rd round ($p=p_i+2*p_a$), [time 5 before the next round] $p=p_i+3*p_a+p_a$ technically $p$ can exceed 1 but you will win in the next round where it will reset to it's initial value $p_i$. If in this example you won on the third round, the 'inbetween' event would have still happened and $p$ would have been $p_i+p_a$.

Comment: I am confused about the additions to the win probability: are there 2 types of them?
If I loose, I gain additional $p_a$ each round until I win. But what do you mean by the last paragraph?  "..in addition to you 'rolling' for a win every k amount of rolls you gain pa which is additive to your current win probability". So this increase of probability happens each k rounds? (Then, after some time, your probability of win would exceeds 1).

Comment: The meaning of the last paragraph is obscure.  Could you perhaps offer a small example of the course of one such game?

Comment: I added some clarifications, to the post, @JakubKoubele yes the probability could potentially exceed 1 in between rounds (ie. would be guaranteed to win in the next). For example if the inbetween increase happened much more frequently than the actual round you could in theory have a probability of 1 to win every round, or on the other end if the inbetween events are exceedingly rare the game 'degenerates' into the simplified case.